# Comparação de valores com o SELECT

Tags: java, sql, select, variáveis

Olá, estou criando um projeto de busca e preciso fazer uma confirmação no meu banco de dados.

Possuo uma tabela "estabelecimentos" no meu banco SQLite, com as seguintes colunas: **id, nome e categoria**. E uma variável do tipo String chamada "**nomeEstab**"

Preciso fazer uma comparação entre o valor da variável e o dados do banco, ou seja, preciso verificar se dentro da coluna **nome** existe algum campo que possua o mesmo valor da variável, caso exista que me retorne um True por exemplo, senão, retorne um False.

Segue os códigos..

**Código SQL**

```
    SQLiteDatabase db = openOrCreateDatabase("pesquisa.db", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);

    StringBuilder sqlEstabelicimento = new StringBuilder();
    sqlEstabelicimento.append("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS [estabelecimentos](");
    sqlEstabelicimento.append("[_id] INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, ");
    sqlEstabelicimento.append("nm_estab VARCHAR(100), ");
    sqlEstabelicimento.append("categoria VARCHAR(50));");

    db.execSQL(sqlEstabelicimento.toString());
```

**Código Java**

```
    public void pesquisar(View view){
    SQLiteDatabase db = openOrCreateDatabase("pesquisa.db", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);

    EditText nomeDigitado = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_NomePesquisa);
    String texto = nomeDigitado.getText().toString();

    try{
     db.execSQL("SELECT nm_estab FROM estabelecimentos WHERE nm_estab = '"+texto+"'");
    }
    catch (Exception erro){

    }
}
```

Comment: Vc já montou seu SQL? Poste ele para o pessoal ajudar vc e poste também seu código em Java.

Comment: Essa sua pergunta não está tão clara. A variável "nomeEstab" vai ser o parâmetro de comparação com o objeto persistido? Se sim, será feita a comparação com quais atributos do objeto persistido no banco de dados? Com todos os atributos?

Answer (score 2):

Este é o SELECT:

```
SELECT * FROM estabelecimentos WHERE nome LIKE '%suaVariavel%'
```

Comment: Obrigado, funcionou perfeitamente